# Unable to login in terminal using cf login IBM Bluemix cloud foundry

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have installed cf CLI on my machine

```
 $ cf -v
  cf version 6.30.0+decf883.2017-09-01
```

When I was trying to connect IBM Bluemix using Cloud Foundry, I got below mention error:

```
$ cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net/
Setting api endpoint to https://api.ng.bluemix.net/...
Request error: Get https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/info: proxy connect tcp: dial tcp: i/o timeout
TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the https_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.
FAILED
```

Most of the time I faced this error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have to specify a proxy in order to get access to this domain from your current network (maybe you are trying to connect from your work).

You have to configure an environment variable called `https_proxy`                                                                          following these steps to specify your proxy: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/http-proxy.html

Comment: yeah, it's working for me. Sometimes internet connectivity may be caused this type of problem.

Comment: i had the same issue with an ubuntu inside a vmware player 12. The issue seems to have disappear by switching the network interface from bridge to nat.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have IPv6 but it's broken (doesn't work) and if your first DNS nameserver is IPv6 (e.g. 2001:4860:4860::8888) and you're on macOS High Sierra (that's what I'm on; I don't know about other OSes/versions):

```
cf api api.run.pivotal.io
Setting api endpoint to api.run.pivotal.io...
Request error: Get https://api.run.pivotal.io/v2/info: dial tcp: i/o timeout
TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the https_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.
```

And here's the output of `tcpdump`; note that the lookups never fallback to using IPv4:

```
sudo tcpdump -ni en0 port 53
Password:
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on en0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
10:56:44.436907 IP6 2001:4870:a2ce:1101:8438:ddac:d38f:704e.61647 > 2001:4860:4860::8888.53: 49963+ AAAA? api.run.pivotal.io. (36)
10:56:44.436910 IP6 2001:4870:a2ce:1101:8438:ddac:d38f:704e.61648 > 2001:4860:4860::8888.53: 60917+ A? api.run.pivotal.io. (36)
10:56:49.436910 IP6 2001:4870:a2ce:1101:8438:ddac:d38f:704e.61652 > 2001:4860:4860::8888.53: 20369+ AAAA? api.run.pivotal.io. (36)
10:56:49.436915 IP6 2001:4870:a2ce:1101:8438:ddac:d38f:704e.61653 > 2001:4860:4860::8888.53: 50584+ A? api.run.pivotal.io. (36)
10:57:16.868818 IP 10.80.130.88.57117 > 10.87.8.10.53: 3480+ A? csi.gstatic.com. (33)
```